# Change admin theme in a ongoing project

Tags: django, themes

I have developed a project in django as core technology and i need to change the admin theme but cant change it can any one specify an experienced steps for this process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create your own theme, you need to override admin 'static files' and 'templates'.
Otherwise, the best way is to use an already available theme like https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet

Comment: Thanks for the reference but i need to add the theme which was specified by the client ,thanks again

Comment: Is it an already available theme? Or you do you want to implement it according to clients design.

Comment: client gave the theme i had to do accordingly